# php regex match pattern

Tags: php, regex

Im using the following regex to match the string below, so far so good. Now, how could I make the content of BAZ optional so it matches cases where BAZ ()

```
$str = '- 10 TEST (FOO 3 TEST.BAR 213 BAZ (\HELLO) TEST';

preg_match('/FOO (\d+).+BAR (\d+).+BAZ \(\\\\(\w+)\)/i', $str, $match);

$str = '- 10 TEST (FOO 3 TEST.BAR 213 BAZ () TEST';
$array = array(
    'FOO' => 3,
    'BAR' => 213,
    'BAZ' => 
);
```

Comment: Using the operator '?' maybe? I don't understand exactly what you want

Comment: Where did your previous question go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to wrap the whole thing in a non-capturing group and add a `?` operator.

```
/FOO (\d+).+BAR (\d+).+BAZ (?:\(\\\\(\w+)\))?/i
```

Note that this captures BAZ with no parentheses after it. If you're looking for BAZ () instead, use this:

```
/FOO (\d+).+BAR (\d+).+BAZ \((?:\\\\(\w+))?\)/i
```

Answer (score 1):

To make something optional you can put it in a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` then place a question mark after the group. The question mark is a quantifier that means "zero or one".

In other words, change this:

```
\\\\(\w+)
```

to this:

```
(?:\\\\(\w+))?
```

So the entire expression becomes:

```
/FOO (\d+).+BAR (\d+).+BAZ \((?:\\\\(\w+))?\)/i
```